# running a script from a directory in ipython

Tags: python, scripting, path, ipython

im pretty new to all of this so please try to bear with me.
I've got a directory set up where i dump all the scripts im working on,
and i'm trying to make it so that i can run the scripts from within that directory directly from ipython.
so far, ive add an **init**.py to the aforementined directory,
and have tried appending the path to sys.path,
however, even after i successfully append the path, trying to use the run command for any script in the directory results in a not found error.
another problem i have, is that after every kernel reset the sys.path seems to reset to its previous values, without the new path settings i enter.
grateful for any help,
ron

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path` only affects imports, not IPython's `%run`. The run magic is like calling `python script.py` - you have to cd into the directory where scripts are, or pass the full path to those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run scripts with ipython from a directory, you could put ipython in the shebang and add the directory to your path, like so:

The script would be like this (python3 example):

```
#!/usr/bin/ipython

print("HI from ipython")
```

And then you'd add the directory where the script is to the PATH enviroment variable (if you're using Linux or other *NIX):

```
export PATH="/home/ron/ipython_scripts:$PATH"
```

Now, you should make them executable:

```
chmod +x /home/ron/ipython_scripts/script.py
```

Now you can use the script anywhere :)

```
$ script.py
HI from ipython
```

Answer (score -1):

in Ipython notebook type : `%run script_name.py`